# PHP echo work but preg_match doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

// I have make some change but preg_match function doesn't work and echo Work. I can not understand what is wrong. I'm going crazy

```
public function crawl()
{
    $html = $this->getPageHTMLContent($this->getDomain().$this->entryPagePath);
    $categoryPageDom = $this->getHtmlDom($html); 

    echo $categoryPageDom->find('div#pagination a.gh', 1)->attr['href'];

    preg_match("/\?p=(.*)&q/", $categoryPageDom->find('div#pagination a.gh', 1)->attr['href'], $machtes);
    var_dump($machtes);
}


public function getPageHTMLContent($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);

     return $contents;
}
```

Comment: remove this line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to URL When i make echo $categoryPageDom->find('div#pagination a.gh', 1)->attr['href']; I get something like this http://www.xxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=iw&artikel=101&detail=mak on the Browser. But when I see the source code, it looks like this http://www.xxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=iw&*amp;*artikel=101&*amp;*detail=mak The problem was **amp;** i have use **str_replace** to remove it. Curl works very well

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a value from curl_download, there's no `return`  statement

Comment: Thank you I could adjust that. But I still have a problem with preg_match it does not work while running echo $categoryPageDom = file_get_html("http://www.spirituosenstore.de/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=2&q=e&x=0&y=0"); 
echo $categoryPageDom->find('div#pagination a.gh', 1)->attr['href'];
preg_match("/\?p=(.*)&q/", $categoryPageDom->find('div#pagination a.gh', 1)->attr['href'], $machtes);
var_dump($machtes);